# 2D Numpy array: very fast update of rows with another array based on criteria column

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython, numba

Let's say I have a 2D Numpy array ***A*** and I want to update specific rows with another array ***B*** based on the id column as criteria.

The thing is I need to have that **in a very fast way**! I tried to do that with Pandas first, but the performance is not good enough. The array A has around 10000 lines and I need to process 100 to 500 of such updates per second.

Is it possible to achieve that with plain Numpy? Or do I need to use Numba or Cython?

```py
A = np.array([
   [1000001,'Peter',11],
   [1000002,'Bob',22],
   [1000003,'Julie',33],
   [1000004,'Larry',44],
   ...
])

B = [
   [1000002,'Bob',77],
   [1000004,'Mia',88],
]
```

The result of ***A*** should look like this:

```py
[
   [1000001,'Peter',11],
   [1000002,'Bob',77],
   [1000003,'Julie',33],
   [1000004,'Mia',88],
   ...
]
```

---

**Update:**

After several attempts I figured out a Numpy solution that works quite well:

```py
def update_array(A, B):
    A[np.where(np.isin(A[:,0], B[:,0]))] = B
    return A
```

Is there an even faster approach in Numpy?
Or does anyone know how to make this work with Numba? When I just put the @jit decorator I get an error message.

---

**Update 2**

The original data streams from a Websocket connection and arrives actually in the format list of dict.

```py
A = [ 
   {'id': 1000001, 'name': 'Peter', 'points': 11}, 
   {'id': 1000002, 'name': 'Bob', 'points': 22}, 
   {'id': 1000003, 'name': 'Julie', 'points': 33}, 
   {'id': 1000004, 'name': 'Larry', 'points': 44}, 
   ... 
]

B = [ 
   {'id': 1000002, 'name': 'Bob', 'points': 77}, 
   {'id': 1000004, 'name': 'Mia', 'points': 88},
]
```

At first I thought it's faster to convert the data into a Pandas DataFrame or a Numpy Array for further processing, but now I have the impression that converting each data package takes more time than the actual data processing.

---

**Update 3**

After trying several approaches I went with a "dict of dict" structure with the id's as keys.
The conversion of the original structure is pretty fast using list comprehension. This implies that all further data processing is now depending heavily on list comprehension too which is not the most readable code in my opinion. Especially since in my case the dicts that I process don't always have the same depth, which produces even more excessive list comprehension. Boy I really went wild with that today... Pandas was a lot better on that side, but I couldn't get the performance there. Now with this dict approach I feel that it's not the most elegant way... but at least I can process around 20.000 dict updates per second which is a great improvement!

```py
A = { 
   1000001: {'name': 'Peter', 'points': 11}, 
   1000002: {'name': 'Bob', 'points': 22}, 
   1000003: {'name': 'Julie', 'points': 33}, 
   1000004: {'name': 'Larry', 'points': 44}, 
   ... 
}

B = { 
   1000002, {'name': 'Bob', 'points': 77}, 
   1000004, {'name': 'Mia', 'points': 88},
}
```

The bottleneck are still the calculations that I do with the data. There I can only achieve around 100 per second, which is why I decided to not do those calculations in realtime but rather at scheduled intervals. I still would like to learn how far it can go with other approaches, it's quite impressive how much of a performance difference there is between plain python approaches. Not to mention Numba or Cython... If someone has further ideas, I'd be happy to learn more!

Comment: How did you get the output? I would suggest using Numba and optimizing your indexing.

Comment: The output is basically array A with the rows at 1000002  and 1000004 being replaced with array B.

Comment: What is the code snippet you used for it?

Comment: I don' have a code with Numpy for that. I have only code with Pandas, but it's not fast enough. I'm still trying to figure out a solution with Numpy.

Comment: pandas is numpy based. Of course using numpy is faster. But definitely use Numba if you need speed.

Comment: Is there only one incident of each id (e.g. 1000002) in A and B?

Comment: Yes I would like to, I just don't know how.  Do you have an idea how to achieve that with Numba?

Comment: I will post a Numpy solution. Turning it into Numba should be fairly easy

Comment: If maximum speed really really matters, you could consider ditching Python completely in favor of C or C++. Even with `numpy`, Python involves trade-offs between execution speed and speed of writing code. In some situations the trade-off isn't worth it.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Surely 500 updates per second is possible in Python (even regular Python, without NumPy), there is no need to switch languages to achieve this moderate level of performance.

Comment: @CarloP Please check out the post and see if it solves. If not, please let me know and I would try to make it even faster.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't disagree, but OP, after finding a good numpy solution, seemed obsessed with the question if there was anything even faster. At some stage, "even faster" will lead you to a compiled language.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way using just Python:

```
A = {
    1000001: ('Peter', 11),
    1000002: ('Bob', 22),
    1000003: ('Julie', 33),
    1000004: ('Larry', 44),
}

B = {
    1000002: ('Bob', 77),
    1000004: ('Mia', 88),
}

A.update(B)
```

Then A is:

```
{
    1000001: ('Peter', 11),
    1000002: ('Bob', 77),
    1000003: ('Julie', 33),
    1000004: ('Mia', 88)
}
```

My laptop can do that `A.update(B)` about 4 million times per second.

---

Here's a Pandas solution, but on the small sample data provided it is 1000x slower:

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame(A)
dfB = pd.DataFrame(B)

dfA[0] = dfA[0].astype(int)
dfB[0] = dfB[0].astype(int)

dfA.set_index(0, inplace=True)
dfB.set_index(0, inplace=True)

dfA.update(dfB)
```

Now dfA is:

```
             1   2
0                 
1000001  Peter  11
1000002    Bob  77
1000003  Julie  33
1000004    Mia  88
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal John, but I would like to avoid using pandas simply for the fact that the most time is actually consumed by converting the original data into a pandas DataFrame. The same goes for converting into a dict like you use above. I think I can gain a lot of performance if I avoid converting the data as much as possible.

Comment: @CarloP: What is the original format of the data?  Does it come from a file?

Comment: The original data streams from a Websocket connection and arrives actually in the format list of dict. I have updated my thread above accordingly.

Comment: Right, I see you've decided to use `dict` which is what was the fastest in my testing too.  That's good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you update with Numpy (Numba should work the same):

```
A[np.isin(A[:,0],B[:,0])]=B
```

output:

```
[['1000001' 'Peter' '11']
 ['1000002' 'Bob' '77']
 ['1000003' 'Julie' '33']
 ['1000004' 'Mia' '88']]
```

Comment: This is 100x slower than just using `dict` as shown in my answer.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Of course a dict (hash table) search is faster than list search. But, shouldn't you convert array to dict and back to array as well? not sure how long that takes though. Not even sure if OP cares about data structure anyways. Good solutions you provided. Hope it solves the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Ehsan, this is pretty much the approach that I posted above just without using np.where(), right? Acc. to my tests the performance is quite similar for both, np.where() is a little bit faster, but rather insignificant. Interestingly the performance is even slightly worse when using Numba!? (When I say Numba I mean that I have just included the @jit decorator in front of the function, so maybe I'm doing something wrong regarding Numba).

Comment: @CarloP Oh I think I did not see the update when I posted the answer. Using extra np.where must add time (maybe insignificant) and Numba should be faster. Maybe something in your system is different. Also note that using few times vs. using multiple times have different times per operation. If you use the same code many times I expect it to get faster. Lastly, using dict/hash table search is O(1) on average and search on lists are O(n). So if you can store your id as key (like the other answer) it should be significantly faster. Replacing key `name` with value of `id` should be O(n)

Comment: @CarloP I will post time analysis of solutions provided here (including data structure conversion time) later.